# 403 forbidden %3Chtml%3E%3Chead%3E%3Cmeta codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Whats wrong with my code yesterday my code was fine but when i opened it again it displays this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SkoT.jpg)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submitButton').on('click',function(){
        var userid = $('#studentID').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        $('#errorHandler').empty();
            $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: '<?php echo base_url('newsfeed')?>',
            data:{userid:userid,password:password},
            success:function(data){
            if(data)
                $("body").load(data);
            },error:function(errorw){
                if( errorw.status == 400 ) { //Validation error or other reason for Bad Request 400
                  var json = $.parseJSON( errorw.responseText );
                }
                $('#errorHandler').append($('<label class="red-text text-darken-2">'+json+'</label>'));
            }
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

here is my login view

Comment: Post your code not an image.So we can help?

Comment: Looks like URL encoded HTML! `<html><head><meta`

Comment: where do you think i can find it

Comment: running apache server?

Comment: yes i am running apache server it says [Sat Feb 18 22:40:08.336586 2017] [core:error] [pid 2012:tid 1704] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client ::1:50788] AH00127: Cannot map GET /Groupie/%3C!DOCTYPE HTTP/1.1 to file, referer: http://localhost/Groupie/

Comment: xampp or wamp?­

Comment: i am using xampp it was working yesterday :(

Comment: did you change your root directory?

Comment: no i didnt change my root directory

Comment: did load url helper before using base_url?

Comment: yes i did load it

Comment: Then try using `url:"<?php echo base_url('newsfeed')?>"`

Comment: its still doing forbidden

Answer (score 0):

your ajax request's `url` formatting is not correct. you've to use `+` sign before and after `newsfeed`. so it would be like :

```
url: '<?php echo base_url(' + newsfeed + ')?>'
```

or if `newsfeed` isn't a variable then the code would be :

```
url: '<?php echo base_url(\'newsfeed\')?>'
```

Comment: my newsfeed is a custom route frm CI

Comment: I think the second one is the good one. base_url is a CI function requiring a text string indicating the custom route or the default controller/function/parameters.

Comment: im still getting forbidden